# What is the 'tribe' referred to early in Sheepfarmer's Daughter by Elizabeth Moon?

Tags: novel, elizabeth-moon

I am rereading one of my ATF trilogies - The Deed of Paksenarrion by Elizabeth Moon. I haven't read in a while since my paperback is getting fragile and I can't find an ecopy for my nook (which really surprises me).

Early in the first book, Sheepfarmer's Daughter, Paks is on her first campaign with the Duke's mercenary company. When Stammel sends Paks down a path to setup their campsite, he says "Stay on the path; we don't want the tribe angry with us". I don't believe there has been any reference to any tribe at this point. Who are 'the tribe'?

Comment: You can get a DRM-free ebook directly from the publisher: [Baen Books](http://www.baenebooks.com/) (or at least you can when they get their website back online; they're having a server issue right now).  For a Nook, you want to download the ePub version.

Comment: Or a Kobo, ePub is still the ideal.

Comment: The Baen website just came back up.  Here's the direct link for [The Deed of Paksenarrion](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-100-the-deed-of-paksenarrion.aspx).  Note that when you buy the ebook, you get *all* the formats they offer; you don't have to choose just one.

Comment: It should be noted that @cjm linked to the combined three books of the series.

Comment: @Solemnity - I'm pretty sure that you have the correct answer - please post it as an answer so that we can upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a single reference to a tribe previous to this line (I have the ebook, searching-capability)- where Stephi is describing where he got his 'love potions':

> "Well, no, sir, I didn't. But it's a simple sort of thing—lots of the grannies sell it. I usually get it from one of the forest—folk tribes in Aarenis, but we were on the road here, and this little old lady asked did I want anything. I'm sure it's all right, sir, and even if it's not, I never took it."

It didn't establish a name, if one existed, for that tribe.  Aarenis was south (by 'Aerenis' definition), but not by an established distance.

The novel did not provide a map.  A few fan-made maps exist, but are not worth linking-to as an answer.

Unfortunately, not all novels have their characters and groups drawn-out with a Dramatis Personæ.

Comment: I had the impression they were Gypsy-eqivalents, some sort of traveling folk.